# Getting a list of radio station URLs from iTunes?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macos, itunes, internet-radio

I would like to get the same list of radio stations as displayed by iTunes. I think it's a dynamic list.

Any suggestions on how/where I can obtain the same list of radio stations? I would like to do this in objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.shoutcast.com has a developer API.